# Shrink divs to fit inside other div

Tags: javascript

I have a fixed-size parent div in which a 16 * 16 grid of child divs fits perfectly. I need to figure out a way to ensure that if I want a 15*15 grid or a 17*17 grid that the child divs automatically resize to fit the parent. Ie the child divs get bigger or smaller depending on the number called in the prompt.

I'm still a beginner and have tried a few different CSS tools (CSS grid and flex-boxes) but I've only been able to get the boxes to scroll down or increase the size of the parent div, not decrease or increase the size of the child divs as necessary.

This builds the grid:

```
var size = prompt("How many squares?");

function buildGrid(size) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "container";
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  for (i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.className = "square";
    container.appendChild(square);
  }
}

//CALL FUNCTION
buildGrid(size);
```

And here's the corresponding CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 384px;
    height: 384px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;

}


.square {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px; 
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  float: left;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically resize the children to fit the parent but struggling.

Comment: You should set the sizes in the javascript. Then it’s just 384/count, subtract 1 for your padding, then take the remainder off the last one (since 384 won’t be evenly divisible by all numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I have tweaked your code a bit, and have minused border-offset from actual width to fit the small ones inside the big-grid. I've also included flexbox with wrap property to achieve what you tried.

```js
// var size = prompt("How many squares?");

function buildGrid(size) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "container";
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  var numberOfSquares = size * size;
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfSquares; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.className = "square";
    // Minusing 2px from 384px - to adjust the border width
    var borderOffset = size * 2;
    square.style.width = ((384 - borderOffset) / size) + "px";
    container.appendChild(square);
  }
}

//CALL FUNCTION
buildGrid(18);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 384px;
  height: 384px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes! This is it. Your notes are super helpful, too. I'm going to review them so I'm totally sure of what's going on. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try a [percentage width](https://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/):

```
.container {
    width: 10%;
    height: 384px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;

}
```

Or something like that. Adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using percentages.

```
.container {
    width: 384px;
    height: 384px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;

}
```

if your container has width, 384px, and height 384px, then we  compute 22px/384px * 100 = about 5.73. so

```
.square {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px; 
  height: 5.73%;
  width: 5.73%;
  float: left;
}
```